# Comparing two variables in AWK

Tags: awk

I have one issue regarding the comparison of two variables using AWK in LINUX.
For example, with `a=090810` and `b=090910`, it works fine using shell:

```
if [ $a -le $b ]; then
 echo "Hello"
fi
```

However, it does not work using awk:

```
if ( a -le b ) print "Hello"
```

```
if ( a < b ) print "Hello"
```

but this works fine:

```
if ( a < "090910" ) print "Hello"
```

Can anyone help me solving this problem?

Comment: Why do you expect `a -le b` to work in `awk`?

Comment: Sorry, I just made a mistake. I edited it. It should be a < b but my program does not work because a is a variable outside awk.

Comment: When you update a question, do not invalidate existing answers.  I've refixed the question so that the existing answer are not invalidated by your edit.

Comment: You should show us the entire `awk` script.  There are so many ways things could be going 'wrong' it is hard to list them all.  For example, how are you quoting your `awk` script?  How are you providing data to it?  How are you providing the values `a` and `b` to it?  Note that leading zeros in `awk` are removed unless the value within the awk script is (double) quoted.  Also, uninitialized variables map to the empty string or 0, depending on context.  The empty string sorts before `"090910"` legitimately.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the variables to awk from the shell using the -v option:

```
$ x=10
$ y=5
$ echo | awk -v x="$x" -v y="$y" '{print x+y}' 
15
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! In my case, I declared variable b within awk and variable a from shell so I forgot to pass variable b to awk using -v option as you said.  Now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `-le` operator in awk, use `<, >, <=, >=`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {a=090810; b=090910; if(a<b) print "a<b"; if(a>b) print "a>b"}'
a<b
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, I didn't notice about the scope of variable. Your program should work well because both variables are defined within awk. In my case, I declared variable a from shell and variable b in awk, so even I tried <,> it still does not work. Now it works well when I pass variable a from shell to awk